# Need to making a new css version each time I modify it

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with the `CSS reload`. I'm using `HTML webpage` linked to a css file. The problem is when I update that CSS file I need to make a write the new version in the HTML code, like that:

```
<link href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/css/style-custom.css?v=195" rel="stylesheet">
```

By other way the CSS didn't update in the browser. I tried to clear cache, force reload with `command + shift + r` (on mac chrome) but didn't update it, only update when I edit the HTML and write a new version (196, 197...). That's a headache. How I can autoupdate the CSS file in the browser and HTML code without making a new version each time I modify the CSS file? You can see the site [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/habitaciones.html).

Comment: By versioning your css files or disabling your caching on development

Comment: Are you using any server-side code? One method might be to detect the modified date of the CSS file and append that as a timestamp to the file's URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching problem. When the browser requests `/rucab/css/style-custom.css`, the server responds with this header:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
```

This means that the browser may store the file in cache for up to 31536000 seconds (1 year). And most browsers do that. This is a good idea for finished sites, but if you make changes to `style-custom.css`, the browser won't know because it is getting the file from cache.

While you are developing the site, configure the server so that it responds with this header:

```
cache-control: no-cache
```

This will make sure that the browser will **always** fetch the file.

Comment: I inserted that on the header:   <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
But didn't work

Comment: No... That header is for the css file and needs to be sent along the http response.

Comment: How I can insert it in the CSS File?

Comment: What? No. Configure your server to send `cache-control: no-cache` in the header of `style-custom.css`. Are you using Apache?

Comment: I can make htaccess file if u want.

Comment: Yes, you should create an `.htaccess` file and use it to set the header for the CSS files.